# How do I read decomplied Electron ASAR?

Tags: javascript, electron, asar

I decompiled an Electron app using this [article](https://medium.com/how-to-electron/how-to-get-source-code-of-any-electron-application-cbb5c7726c37)

When I went through the code, it didn't look complete.

So [this](https://pastebin.com/uFM6mMBF) is one of the js files. I have no idea if its encrypted or not or how to even read it.

I tried prettifying the js [here](https://pastebin.com/PjJvvWat), but why does it look weird?

How do I read this and run it properly?

Here's a small sample of the javscript:

```js
R200[252478] = global;
R200[211667] = O0hh(R200[252478]);
R200.G577 = G577;
R200[153365] = q5VV(R200[252478]);
R200[621031] = x4hh(R200[252478]);
R200[283444] = (function() {
    var v8j = 2;
    for (; v8j !== 1;) {
        switch (v8j) {
            case 2:
                return {
                    F2l: (function(f2l) {
                        var q3j = 2;
                        for (; q3j !== 10;) {
                            switch (q3j) {
                                case 3:
                                    q3j = y2l === f2l.length ? 9 : 8;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    q3j = D2l < P2l.length ? 3 : 6;
                                    break;
                                case 12:
                                    var e2l = function(V3P) {
                                        var g3j = 2;
                                        for (; g3j !== 1;) {
                                            switch (g3j) {
                                                case 2:
                                                    return l2l[V3P];
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                                    return w2l;
                                    break;
                                case 7:
                                    (D2l++, y2l++);
                                    q3j = 4;
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    var D2l = 0,
                                        y2l = 0;
                                    q3j = 4;
                                    break;
                                case 8:
                                    l2l += N9VV.u9VV(P2l.s9VV(D2l) ^ f2l.s9VV(y2l));
                                    q3j = 7;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    var X2l = function(m2l) {
                                        var L3j = 2;
                                        for (; L3j !== 13;) {
                                            switch (L3j) {
                                                case 4:
                                                    I2l.k9VV(N9VV.u9VV(m2l[N2l] + 65));
                                                    L3j = 3;
                                                    break;
                                                case 8:
                                                    r2l = I2l.T9VV(function() {
                                                        var K3j = 2;
                                                        for (; K3j !== 1;) {
                                                            switch (K3j) {
                                                                case 2:
                                                                    return 0.5 - I9VV.c9VV();
                                                                    break;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }).O9VV('');
                                                    O2l = R200[r2l];
                                                    L3j = 6;
                                                    break;
                                                case 1:
                                                    var N2l = 0;
                                                    L3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 3:
                                                    N2l++;
                                                    L3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 14:
                                                    return O2l;
                                                    break;
                                                case 6:
                                                    L3j = !O2l ? 8 : 14;
                                                    break;
                                                case 2:
                                                    var I2l = [];
                                                    L3j = 1;
                                                    break;
                                                case 9:
                                                    var r2l, O2l;
                                                    L3j = 8;
                                                    break;
                                                case 5:
                                                    L3j = N2l < m2l.length ? 4 : 9;
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                                    var l2l = '',
                                        P2l = m9VV(X2l([6, -10, -12, -10])());
                                    q3j = 5;
                                    break;
                                case 9:
                                    y2l = 0;
                                    q3j = 8;
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    l2l = l2l.a9VV('#');
                                    var L2l = 0;
                                    var w2l = function(F3P) {
                                        var Z3j = 2;
                                        for (; Z3j !== 20;) {
                                            switch (Z3j) {
                                                case 2:
                                                    Z3j = L2l === 0 && F3P === 192 ? 1 : 4;
                                                    break;
                                                case 4:
                                                    Z3j = L2l === 1 && F3P === 162 ? 3 : 9;
                                                    break;
                                                case 1:
                                                    l2l.M9VV.G9VV(l2l, l2l.r9VV(-3, 3).r9VV(0, 2));
                                                    Z3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 5:
                                                    return (L2l++, l2l[F3P]);
                                                    break;
                                                case 7:
                                                    Z3j = L2l === 3 && F3P === 90 ? 6 : 14;
                                                    break;
                                                case 9:
                                                    Z3j = L2l === 2 && F3P === 23 ? 8 : 7;
                                                    break;
                                                case 8:
                                                    l2l.M9VV.G9VV(l2l, l2l.r9VV(-5, 5).r9VV(0, 4));
                                                    Z3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 14:
                                                    Z3j = L2l === 4 && F3P === 194 ? 13 : 12;
                                                    break;
                                                case 12:
                                                    Z3j = L2l === 5 && F3P === 138 ? 11 : 10;
                                                    break;
                                                case 10:
                                                    w2l = e2l;
                                                    Z3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 11:
                                                    l2l.M9VV.G9VV(l2l, l2l.r9VV(-7, 7).r9VV(0, 6));
                                                    Z3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 6:
                                                    l2l.M9VV.G9VV(l2l, l2l.r9VV(-5, 5).r9VV(0, 4));
                                                    Z3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 13:
                                                    l2l.M9VV.G9VV(l2l, l2l.r9VV(-6, 6).r9VV(0, 5));
                                                    Z3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                                case 3:
                                                    l2l.M9VV.G9VV(l2l, l2l.r9VV(-8, 8).r9VV(0, 6));
                                                    Z3j = 5;
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                                    q3j = 12;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })('D#&P6)')
                };
                break;
        }
    }
})();
```